PDF javascripts in browsers for RPG character sheets
I'm very new to PDF scripting and there are a couple of issues i don't understand.
I want to create a PDF file that can dynamically handle input fields to help by friend with his homemade RPG game. The idea is to have a sheet where you can select the weapon you will use and the relevant dices show up + if something important is happening its highlighted with color.
I managed most of it, but if i want to use javascript to change text color or add new elements to a combobox it just doesn't work in browsers!
I downloaded Adobe PDF viewer and in that i can see that my color changes work just fine, but have no effect in browser.
I tried to see the  difference and this.getField("textfield1").value can be changed, but this.getField("textfield1").textColor = color.red  or this.getField("textfield1").textColor = ["RGB", 0, 102/255, 153/255]; doesn't work only in Adobe
is there a safety reason why this is happening?
